# Values the same but not equal

Tags: c, pointers

Can somebody explain to me why the following code outputs `0 0`. I was under the impression that mathematically `a-b == 0` ⇒ `a == b`

```
char* V1 = "hello, world!\n";

main(){
  F1(V1);
}

F1(A1){
  printf("%u %u\n", V1 - A1, V1 == A1);
}
```

Comment: Don't tell me you really wrote that code.....

Comment: This is a minimal viable example from someone else's buggy code... They claim it works fine in Visual Studio...

Comment: `==` comparisons on strings in C don't mean what you think it means.

Comment: And neither does `V1 - A1`.

Comment: It [works for me](http://ideone.com//3htZye) (after you fix all the obvious bugs).

Comment: Your last edit just increased the number of bugs in the code, which is quite an achievement!

Comment: Changed to '%u', but that doesn't change the output

Comment: @user12341234: see the [link in my comment above](http://ideone.com/3htZye) for bug-fixed code.

Comment: @user12341234 'They claim it works fine in Visual Studio' - what about when you tried it?

Comment: It outputs `0 0` on my system. Presumably on theirs this would output `0 1`, though their original code was quite different from this version.

Comment: Use `printf("%d\n", V1 == A1); printf("%td\n", V1 - A1);` to print valid results.  It `"%td"` not available, use `printf("%d\n", (int) (V1 - A1));`  Still  other UB exists.

Comment: On my machine `A1` is an int not a pointer, so the type of `V1 - A1` is actually `char *` not `ptrdiff_t`

Answer (score 2):

As per the `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.6, two pointers can only any only be subtracted if they are from same array object.

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined,
>   and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header.
>   If the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undefined. [...]

That said, you should be using `%td` for printing a result of type `ptrdiff_t`, generated from pointer subtraction.

Next, coming to the usage of `==` operator, it cannot be used to compare the contents of the string (array), it basically compares the pointers themselves (not the content they point to).

Comment: Ok, so the reason the two values don't equal each other is because it's undefined behavior?

Comment: @user12341234 Primarily, it's bad code (no offense), secondly, `==` is not the same as `strcmp()`, thirdly, you're right.

Comment: Re firstly: No offense taken, I didn't write this, just simplified it. Re secondly: I don't think the original intent was to compare string content, but the pointers. Re thirdly: thanks.

Comment: Don't those "pointers" both point to the same array object though? I'm not sure that that specifically is the source of the undefined behavior

Answer (score 2):

As @SouravGhosh pointed out, there is undefined behavior here. Still, it is interesting to understand why the second printed value is sometimes 0 and sometimes 1 (depending on the machine it runs on).

The absence of an explicit type for the input of `F` means that `A1` is implicitly an `int`. The function call `F(V1)` thus casts the pointer `V1` to an `int`. On some machines this might be a narrowing conversion, which is why on some machines the comparison `V1 == A1` is true while on other machines it is false. Perhaps on some machines both arguments in `V1 - A1` are cast to ints (hence the value 0) but in the comparison `V1 == A1` (which is ub) tries to cast `A1` to a valid address and either fails or casts it to a different address.

Comment: But if the values were the same, and there were a narrowing then wouldn't both operands of the `==` get downcast and still be equal?

Comment: Good question. Comparing an integer to a pointer is undefined behavior, hence the comparison is undefined. In any event, `V1 == V1` *is true and `A1 == V1` sometimes evaluates to false, and the implicit cast from `pointer` to `int` is the only place where a discrepancy between the two sides of the comparison could have been introduced. Maybe the problem isn't narrowing per se but the conversion to a signed number.